# Access web camera from Excel web add-in

Tags: office-js

I am using Excel web add-in and would like to access images from a user’s web camera.
I cannot get access to the web camera through normal html5 in Excel. Neither through old school flash.
Perhaps the user can take photos outside of office, that gets stored in a local folder, and my Excel Addin, can look in that folder every second to see if a file is added?
Any suggestions on how to get access to a local folder?

Comment: You have this tagged for both `vsto` and `office-js`. These are two completely different stacks. Could you clarify which stack you are using?

Comment: Have removed those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OfficeJs runs within a web container, it doesn't have access to the local drive or network ports. If this is for personal automation, you could spin-up a web server, such as node server, and expose an API that add-in can interface with. The function of the server web would be to act as a file server and serve the file content over HTTP to the add-in abstracting the storage tier.

If this is a production class add-in, then it is better to store the file on a cloud storage service that offers API level access to the file (such as OneDrive).